# how to check if 2 ids are in an array in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

i have an object in mongodb. I have a Chat collection.

Chat have a property: users (array of ids)

I need pass 2 `ids` in a query, but i dont know how to check if these 2 ids are in "users" Array.

I tried:

```
const { users } = req.body; // return ['1223adas','131312312'
const chats = await Chat.findOne({ users: { $in: [users[0], users[1]] } });
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not precise enough. What is the error message exactly? Please edit your post with this information.

Comment: it doesnt work means, only check 1 user. No errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to find the document that has `users` field contains all items in your array, you can use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator. Example:

```
Chat.findOne({ users: { $all: users } });
```